# Cancel hover action on when mouse leaves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to keep a navi item lit up when mouse is in dropdown area. But when mouse leaves, parent still gets hover background value.

Basic html would be

```
<div class="mainnav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and my jquery code for it

```
$(".main-nav ul li ul").each(function(){
    var bgcolor = "{{settings.main_navi_clr3}}";
    $(this).hover(function(){

      $(this).parent().css('background-color',bgcolor);
      $(this).parent().find('a').css('color','#fff');
      $(this).find('a').css('color',bgcolor);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to use `addClass` and `removeClass`.

jQuery

```
$(".main-nav ul li ul").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('hover');
    });
);
```

CSS

```
.main-nav ul li.hover {
    background-color: #000; /* bgcolor */
}

.main-nav ul li.hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.main-nav ul li.hover ul a {
    color: #000; /* bgcolor */
}
```